# Typescript 0.9.1.1 module splitted into several .ts files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to define parts of a module over several files. I compile the following TypeScripts with the `--module amd` flag and load the builded JavaScript files using the **require.js** library.

**File: rm.ts**

```
export module rm {
   export function init():void {
       console.log("rm.init() called");
       this.candidate.init();
   }
}
```

**File: candidate.ts**

```
export module rm.candidate {
    export function init() {
        console.log("rm.candidate.init() called");
    }
}
```

**File: main.js (For require.js)**

```
require(["rm"], function (exports) {
    console.log(exports);
    exports.rm.init();
});
```

This call: `this.candidate.init()` won't work, since **candidate.js** wasn't included by **require.js**.

How can I define the dependency of **candidate.ts** in **rm.ts**? Is it possible "sub-modules" to be defined across multiple files, as I try it?

With these adjustments to **rm.ts** it works, but it does not seem to be the intended way.

```
import candidateTS = require("candidate");
export module rm {

   export var candidate = candidateTS.rm.candidate;

   export function init():void {
       console.log("rm.init() called");
       this.candidate.init();
   }
}
```

Maybe I should mention that I work with TypeScript for the first time. Almost all examples over the web which treat this subject, refer to older versions of TypeScript, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I cover the fact that you don't need to namespace typescript external modules here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: Your adjustment above seems to be exactly the right way to do it. It is the "intended way" to define an AMD module with dependencies on other AMD modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a module loader, you would normally drop the `module` declarations and treat your files as the module. For example...

File: candidate.ts

```
export function init() {
    console.log("rm.candidate.init() called");
}
```

File: rm.ts

```
import c = require('candidate');
export function init():void {
    console.log("rm.init() called");
    c.init();
}
```

You can see that you load them using the `import` statement and the alias you give (for example `c` below) is the handle for the loaded module.

```
import c = require('candidate');

c.init();
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I'm still too used to JS objects. I will try your solution tomorrow at work and accept your answer then. Thank you very much!